# Speeding up SQL query with 56 million records on simple table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table that look like this (snapshot of SequelPro):

[image]

[image]

It contains ~56M rows. They have been indexed with `uniprot_id` and `gene_symbol` as keys.
What I want to do is to perform the following simple SQL query:

```
SELECT uniprot_id, gene_symbol
FROM id_mapping_uniprotkb
```

And later store them into Python's dictionary.
The problem is that the above SQL query takes very long time to finish.
What's the way to speed it up?

Here is my Python code:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
condb = mdb.connect(host = "db01.foo.com.jp",
                     user = "coolguy",
                     passwd = "xxxx",
                     db = "CISBP_DB",
                     cursorclass = mdb.cursors.SSCursor
                     )
crsr = condb.cursor()
sql = """
          SELECT uniprot_id, gene_symbol
          FROM id_mapping_uniprotkb
          """
crsr.execute(sql)
rows = crsr.fetchall()
#gene_symbol2uniprot = dict(crsr.fetchall())

gene_symbol2uniprot = {}
for uniprotid,gene_symbol in rows:
    gene_symbol2uniprot[gene_symbol] = uniprotid

# do something with gene_symbol2uniprot
# with other process.
```

Comment: What is a long time, and how are you going to be using the resulting dictionary? All of its elements, or just some?

Comment: The first step in such cases is to run [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) which will tell you _how_ the database is processing your query - more specifically, it will tell you (among other things) if any indexes were being used, if the disk was being used as cache, etc.

Comment: Store it as pickle??? Why?

Comment: Rather than waiting for the entire query to finish, you can stream the result from sql server. In the application side you can start processing the result rows without waiting for the entire result set. I don't know what are the libraries available in python to do such streaming. you can look up on web.

Comment: The query reads all rows from disk; an `explain` will tell you nothing here.  Most likely, the bottleneck is not in the database, but in the transfer from the disk to the database process, or the database process to your Perl script.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. You're downloading 100s of Mbs, this will always take time. Perhaps describe the problem you're trying to solve, and get help there.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Forget about pickle. The bottom line I'll use this table as source to check another test.

Comment: You are reading ALL 56 million rows.  It's already running as fast as it can, the index is not necessary for this query (no WHERE clause, no ORDER BY), and the limiting factor is the network transfer rate (and probably you'll run out of memory).

Comment: In this case your hard disk or solid state disk is also important. You are trying to collect 1.3 gb. This is reletivly big. What are use using for storage?

Comment: At first glance, this seems to be your problem: `rows = crsr.fetchall()` - you are fetching everything at once. Just step through the cursor instead `for row in crsr:`.

Comment: @JimGarrison: `MemTotal:49447632 kB`

Comment: If you can describe what you are doing _"do something with gene_symbol2uniprot"_, then people can suggest something that will solve your problem. @Korem is right, this is starting to look like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why on earth do you need 56 million records in memory? If you can explain that, we may be able to help. Databases are good at picking a few relevant records out of millions, it's what they're optimised for. If you just want all rows every time, don't use a database at all...

Answer (score 4):

Transferring 65 Million records across the wire is never going to be quick, especially if the records are more than a few bytes each. The database shouldn't add much overhead but it's not giving you any value.

Normally I'd say you never need to do what you're trying, but I'm guessing from the table names that this is something to do with genomes and proteins, so it's possible you're doing something that really does require the data. A little clarification in the question would help us answer more usefully.

Anyway...

The database is designed to filter and sort massive data sets until they're at a manageable size. Since you're always getting every record, you'd find it a lot faster to store the data in a compressed format on disk. The Cpu overhead of decompression will be more than offset by the reduced time to read from disk in all but the smallest data sets.

If you're stuck using MySql for the time being, you should enable [protocol compression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/compression.html). This will reduce the size of the data going over the wire and should speed things up at the expense of Cpu. The same may apply to [compressing the table on disk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-usage.html), but that will be down to how beefy your Sql server is, how much data it can fit into cache, how recently the table was accessed and a host of other details.

A better solution would be to read the records from the database in (say) 1 million record chunks, pickle and/or zip them and write them to disk locally (preferably on an SSD). After you've done this process once, you can deserialize the local copy which should be considerably faster than using a remote database.

#### Edit:

I thought I should add that if you don't need all of the records in memory *at the same time* then there's no reason you can't page (`SELECT a, b, c FROM x LIMIT 200, 50` would get you records #200-249)

Comment: This is—at best—a band-aid stuck on the actual problem. Absent metrics, I strongly suspect the largest cost to be representing the entire database in core and wire protocols would have little to do with that.

Comment: @msw Little to do with ... What? Wire protocols as mentioned when I linked to protocol compression or db storage when I mention disk compression? That said you're right about a lack of metrics

Answer (score 2):

People often get used to loading entire databases in core; this makes for very easy coding until you reach the limit of what you can comfortably fit in real (not virtual) memory.

As soon as keeping-it-all-in-core exhausts some resource, performance plummets. Do you really need `fetchall()` or could you use `for row in cursor:` instead? Put another way, if you can't select, reduce, or somehow summarize the contents of the database, you're not doing useful computation with the data.

(This is just a blunt summary of various comments above.)